# Compare installed Windows updates against defined array

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I would like to check if selected updates are installed on a certain computer.

This is my attempt so far:

```
$HotfixInstaled = Get-Hotfix | Select-Object -Property HotFixID | out-string
$HotfixRequared = @("KB4477029", "KB4486458", "KB4480959")


Compare-Object $HotfixRequared $HotfixInstaled -Property HotFixID | where {$_.sideindicator -eq "<="}
```

The main problem is, that `Compare-Object` could't find items that are in `$HotfixRequared` and in both variables at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. The `Out-String` makes it hard to compare the objects since you destroy the array structure of the returned object and create a string-array with every letter being its own field. Don't do that.
2. You have to use the `-IncludeEqual` Switch of `Compare-Object` and change your `Where-Object` query in the same manner.

This should give you all Hotfixes that are in `$HotfixRequarded` and in both:

```
$HotfixInstaled = Get-Hotfix | Select-Object -Property HotFixID
$HotfixRequared = @("KB4477029", "KB4486458", "KB4480959")


Compare-Object $HotfixRequared ($HotfixInstaled.HotFixID) -IncludeEqual| Where-Object {$_.sideindicator -eq "<=" -or $_.sideindicator -eq "=="}
```